# Xmonad keyboard not working (Macbook pro)

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, lightdm, macbook, xmonad

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Macbook Pro retina (11,1) and it all worked swimmingly.

Then I tried installing Xmonad, selected it once from my lightdm manager and now it loads by default. (The loading by default is my bad since I told Ubuntu to not show lightdm when I turned on the machine, but rather log me in automatically).

My problem is that alt-shift-enter or alt-shift-Q does not work in xmonad. This is likely because I have a Mac keyboard.

What are the correct key combinations for a Macbook in Xmonad?

Ps. I can only assume xmonad actually starts; I have no way of knowing since all I see is a black screen. It does however show the Ubuntu logo if I power it off, so I assume it is running Ubuntu with xmonad as the window manager.

Psps. I have no xmonad config file, to make sure it boots with the standard settings.